# Update ALL records in active record - codeignighter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

Im trying to update all records in the `DB`, there is no key and no where clause.

But im getting an error saying I must specify a `where clause`.

```
    $data = array('views' => 0);
    $this->db->update_batch('table_places', $data);
```

Comment: I don't know this approach to work with db, so I can't show you by code.. but maybe you can set a "where 1=1" in this update to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply using

```
$data = array('views' => 0);
$this->db->update('table_places', $data)
```

will update all the records in the table_places database for you.

`update_batch()` is used for updating multiple rows in your table with *different* data.